# grep and sort options

Tags: grep, sort

I have the following column headers:

```
EntryDate,HH_ID,HH_type,ID#,Age,First,Last,Gender,Race,Ethnicity,CaseWorkerName
```

There is about 2000 rows of data that much match up.

I would like to sort by `CaseWorkerName` and have all the values in the other columns line up.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: `sort` is usually the best option to sort columnated input...

Comment: Does the file contain the header on the first line? Should that be part of the output? Is the data numeric (integer or floats?), or text?

Answer (score 7):

The `CaseWorkerName` is column 11. The `sort` utility may be told what column to sort by, and what delimiter to use when specifying columns:

```
$ sort -t ',' -k11,11 data.in
```

This will tell `sort` to use commas as delimiters and sort in ascending lexicographical order based column 11 to 11 (i.e. only column 11).

The output is written to the console. If you want to store the output in another file, use

```
$ sort -t ',' -k11,11 -o data.out data.in
```

It is ok to specify `data.in` as output file if you use the `-o` flag to do it.

If you wish to avoid sorting the first line (it may contain the column headers), then we must first separate the header from the data:

```
$ head -n 1 data.in >data.header
$ sed '1d' data.in  >data.unsorted
```

Then sort and reunite the sorted data with the header:

```
$ sort -t ',' -k1,11 -o data.sorted data.unsorted
$ cat data.header data.sorted >data.out
$ rm data.sorted data.header data.unsorted
```

Or, shorter

```
$ sed '1d' data.in  | sort -t ',' -k11,11 -o data.sorted
$ head -n 1 data.in | cat - data.sorted >data.out
$ rm data.sorted
```

If you're on a Linux system using GNU coreutils, this may be made even shorter,

```
$ ( head -n 1; sort -t ',' -k11,11 ) <data.in >data.out
```

With the GNU coreutils implementation of `head`, the standard input to the subprocess (`(...)`) will be consumed first by `head` while any remaining data is given to `sort`. The output from the subprocess will be the output from `head` followed by the output from `sort`.

On other systems, `head` might consume more than expected from the standard input stream, which will give `sort` nothing (or at least not the rest of the file) to work with. This is the case on at least OpenBSD.

The result is in `data.out` after each example above.

Note, all of these approaches will fail if the data in any column contains a comma...

Comment: @don_crissti This works only with GNU coreutils.  On my system, this will only return the header row. Will add it with a comment.

Comment: @don_crissti I'll see what I can do and what thoughts the OpenBSD people have about this.

Comment: @don_crissti There's something else that is wrong from what I first thought though.  `(head -n 1; tail -n 1) <file` does the right thing, but `(head -n 1; sort) <file` does not...

Comment: I'm just curious (as I'd like to ask a Q but I only have access to linux setups) if you don't mind (and if/when you have the time)... If you run the following on your BSD setup: `printf %s\\n {1..4} >infile` and then `{ grep -q 2; cat; } <infile` does it print the last two lines (`3` and `4`) ?

Comment: @don_crissti No problems.  The second command produces no output. To be sure this wasn't an issue with `ksh93`, I also tested in `bash` and `pdksh` with the same non-output result.  I have submitted this in a mail to the `openbsd-users` mailing list, but I'm considering filing a proper bug report.

Comment: Thank you ! And sorry for bothering you with such requests. I don't get any output with that second command either although per the standards I think I should ? I'll post a question about this in a few minutes...